# Return values from current month

Tags: excel, date, google-sheets, formulas

My goal is to return each row of the current month to a separate worksheet so I can easily distribute and not have to copy out the data from a given month.

Thru my searching I've been able to construct the below formula but it's not exactly what I need and I have no idea what other factors I'm missing.

The 'Data' worksheet on column 'A' beginning at row 3 and below contains all the dates I want the formula to check against and return each row of the current month to my 'Current Month' worksheet. Also, in the 'Data' worksheet there are a total of 20 columns from 'A' to 'U'

```
=INDEX('Data'!A3:A800000, (MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1), 'Data'!A3:A800000, 0)))
```

I've only been able to get this far. The formula I have will return the first day of the current month from the 'Data' worksheet. Lastly, as I add new rows to the 'Data' worksheet I need the formula to accept them. I didn't know another way to do so unless I gave the parameters 'A3:800000'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query would be a good function to use.. A little tricky without seeing your data but for january, try:

```
=query(Data!A3:U, "select * where A is not null and month(A)+1 = 1 ", 0)
```

change the '1' before the second double quote to 2 for february, etc...

For an automatic calculation of THIS month, you can also try:

```
=query(Data!A3:U, "select * where A is not null and month(A)+1 = "&month(today())&" ", 0)
```

Note:

- according to your locale, you may have to change the comma's to semi-colons.
- make sure col A is formatted as date.

Comment: Thanks! the automatic formula worked great. I changed the ending '1' to a '0' and got EXACT results I needed... you unstuck me.. Thank You

Comment: Glad to hear. Can I bother you 'accept' my anser then ?

Answer (score 0):

For reference...

If data expands multiple years, the below code will give you current month of current year.

```
=query(Data!A3:U, "select * where A is not null and Month(A)+1 = "&MONTH(today())&" and Year(A) = "&YEAR(TODAY())&" ", 0)
```